# Google email migration for general users

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-email-migration

can i create an a app that uses Google migration api .. to migrate  my emails from outlook and yahoo to  my gmail account .. is the api available to be used for a regular gamil account.
The prerequisites in the  documentation is very confusing.[prerequsities  for migration api](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-migration/v2/guides/prerequisites)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration API does not work with consumer Google Accounts (like @gmail.com). For Google Apps for Business and EDU, you can use an OAuth token authorized by the regular user and migrate mail directly to that user account as long as the domain administrator has allowed user email migrations. Instructions for admins to do so are at:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/176213

under Google Apps Requirements. This API is how the Google Apps Migration for MS Outlook tool performs user-authenticated migration of mail.